# UIBarButtonItem disappears

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Why would my UIBarButtonItem sometimes disappear?

When you first load the screen (the first in a Tab Bar) it displays fine. However when you navigate to a new screen and then return both left and right buttons disappear. They aren't reacting to touch events either. However, if you go to a second tab and return they suddenly appear.

It must be a recent iOS change 'cos it was working previously.

==== UPDATE

The code is hardly rocket science but here it is:

Screen 1:

In viewDidLoad:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage
                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                        target:self
                                                        action:@selector(myAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

and

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id) sender {
MyController *mc = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyController" bundle:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Have you tried putting this in viewDidAppear?

Comment: I currently encounter that in a uinaigation inside uitabbar without any moves in `iOS 9.2`

Comment: Is the navigation bar title really big?  Or the title of one of the other bar buttons?  I'm dealing with this now and I think that's what's up.